# AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'tzinfo' Datetime Django

Tags: python, sql, django

Im having a trouble how to set default date in my models, the format should I have in my database is `date` not `datetime` but the resources mostly I find is the code below, Is there any way how to set my models into date? Thanks in advance!

The output/format saved in database should like this

```
2020-11-24
```

[Format of my date in  sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV1NJ.png)

```
from datetime import datetime 
class Person(models.Model):
      date_upload = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now().strftime ("%Y-%m-%d"), blank=True)
```

Comment: Hello @Macky try to add like this `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Comment: Use `models.DateField`

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this:

```
from datetime import date 

class Person(models.Model):
        date_upload = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today(), blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the date in the database, without the time, use `DateField`.

Then just use `date.today` as the `default` for the field. Since `date.today` is a callable, it will call this method each time a new instance of this model is created.

```py
from datetime import date

class Person(models.Model):
    date_upload = models.DateField(default=date.today, blank=True))
```

You can also just use [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) or [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) to automatically set it to today:

```py
    # Set on creation and additional saves
    date_upload = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True))

    # Only set on creation
    date_upload = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True))
```